# jQuery: fade through span containers

Tags: jquery

Have this HTML

```
<span style="display:none">slogan 1</span>
<span style="display:none">slogan 2</span>
<span style="display:none">slogan 3</span>
```

Have this JS:

```
var timer = 0;
$('.banner').children('span').each(function(index) {
  timer = timer + 2000;
  $(this).delay(2500*index).fadeIn(timer, 'linear').fadeOut('3000', 'linear');
});
```

JS basically cycles through each span fading them in and out.
But it does it only ONCE (from slogan 1 to slogan 3).
I want to somehow cycle spans as many times as I want.
for(){} does it improper ways.

Could you help me in this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(function fade(num, idx, cycles) {
  var
    spans = $('span'),
    idx = idx || 0, idx = idx < spans.length ? idx : 0,
    cycles = typeof cycles === 'undefined' ? num * spans.length : cycles;

  if (cycles > 0) {
    spans.eq(idx).fadeIn().fadeOut(function () {
      fade(num, idx + 1, cycles - 1);
    });
  }
}(2 /* two runs total*/));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you - http://jsfiddle.net/ML5b5/1/

```
<span>slogan 1</span>
<span style="display:none">slogan 2</span>
<span style="display:none">slogan 3</span>

var spanCounter = 0;

setInterval(function(){
    var $span = $('span').eq(spanCounter);
    spanCounter = cycleSpan($span, spanCounter);
    spanCounter = (spanCounter >= $('span').length) ? 0 : spanCounter;
}, 3000)

function cycleSpan($span, spanCounter) {
    $span.fadeOut('slow', function(){
        if ($span.next('span').length) {
            $span.next().fadeIn('slow');
        } else {
            $span.siblings('span:first').fadeIn();
        }
    });
    return ++spanCounter;
};
```

This uses a counter variable in the global scope, which I don't really like, but you could try refactoring it to take it out. This code essentially loops through the spans and sends it to a cycle function which will hide the current span and show the next one. You might want to update these spans with a class so they don't mess up the rest of your documents.

Comment: Thanks. But I want to set a max number of times it will cycle. Are there less coding solutions? This seems to be a long one! =)

Comment: I'm a bit confused, do you want it to loop continuously over all your spans or do you just want it to loop once through a set number of spans? If you want to limit the number of times it loops, you just need to have another counter and clear the interval when you reach it.